# Gerar PDF no admin do django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Como eu gero um PDF no admin do django? eu já tenho as views, consigo gerar no frontend com `HTML` tudo certinho, mas como coloco um botão no admin pra gerar ou redirecionar para o link do pdf? estou perdido nisso.

```
class EmpresaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('nome', 'telefone', 'cnpj',)
        search_fields = ('nome', 'cnpj',)
        list_filter = ( 'nome', 'cnpj',  'telefone', )

class AssociadoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'endereco', 'telefone', 'cpf', 'data_filiacao', 'data_nascimento' )   
    search_fields = ('nome', 'cpf',)
    list_filter = ( 'nome', 'cpf',  'telefone', )

class AgendamentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome','inicio', 'fim','assunto', )  
    search_fields = ('nome', 'cpf',)
    list_filter = ( 'nome', 'inicio',  'assunto', )
```

## views

```
class Render:
    @staticmethod
    def render(path: str, params: dict, filename: str):
        template = get_template(path)
        html = template.render(params)
        response = io.BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(
            io.BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), response)
        if not pdf.err:
            response = HttpResponse(
                response.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=%s.pdf' % filename
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Error Rendering PDF", status=400)
```

Comment: Gerar um botão no admin não é dificil. Escolha um dos models e crie uma função que retorna o html do botão.
No admin.py liste o botão como se ele fosse um campo mas inclua ele na lista read_only_fields.

Comment: Como seria esta função amigo? sou novo ainda no django, consegui criar com template no front, mas no admin eu to tentando a mes ja e n consigo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [PDF](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Resolve o que precisa.

Answer (score -1):

tens [aqui](https://medium.com/@hudsonbrendon/gerando-pdf-a-partir-de-html-no-admin-do-django-6f7c3528f5b3) um exemplo de como fazer isso, precisas de utilizar uma ACTION , seria algo assim:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .models import Report

from weasyprint import HTML

class EmpresaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('nome', 'telefone', 'cnpj',)
        search_fields = ('nome', 'cnpj',)
        list_filter = ( 'nome', 'cnpj',  'telefone', )

class AssociadoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome', 'endereco', 'telefone', 'cpf', 'data_filiacao', 'data_nascimento' )   
    search_fields = ('nome', 'cpf',)
    list_filter = ( 'nome', 'cpf',  'telefone', )

class AgendamentoAdmin(DjangoObjectActions, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nome','inicio', 'fim','assunto', )  
    search_fields = ('nome', 'cpf',)
    list_filter = ( 'nome', 'inicio',  'assunto', )

    def generate_pdf(self, request, obj):
        html_string = render_to_string('reports/pdf_template.html', {'obj': obj})

        html = HTML(string=html_string)
        html.write_pdf(target='/tmp/{}.pdf'.format(obj));

        fs = FileSystemStorage('/tmp')
        with fs.open('{}.pdf'.format(obj)) as pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.pdf"'.format(obj)
            return response

        return response

    generate_pdf.label = 'Gerar PDF'
    generate_pdf.short_description = 'Clique para gerar o PDF dessa ordem de serviço'

    change_actions = ('generate_pdf',)
```

NOTA: A opção irá ficar disponível na dropdownlist das actions, onde fica podes efetuar o delete das rows selected. A key de ficar disponível é a última linha do código que partilho...."change_actions = ('generate_pdf',)".